# Calculate_CRC32 function. How do I convert it to calculating bytes and not bits

Tags: c++, crc32

I am helping out a friend of mine who is a bit stuck and my own c++ skills are very rusty. My interest and curiosity is quite picked by this. so I shall try and explain this as best I can. Note its a 32 bit check.

```
uint32_t CRC32::calculate_CRC32(const uint32_t* plData, uint32_t lLength, uint32_t     previousCrc32)
 {
    uint32_t lCount;
    const uint32_t lPolynomial = 0x04C11DB7;
    uint32_t lCrc = previousCrc32;
    unsigned char* plCurrent = (unsigned char*) plData;
    lCrc ^= *plCurrent++;

    while (lLength-- != 0)
     {
       for (lCount = 0 ; lCount < lLength; lCount++)
       {
        if (lCrc & 1)
        lCrc = (lCrc >> 8) ^ lPolynomial;
           else
             lCrc = lCrc >> 8;
        }
    }

    return lCrc;
}
```

Now ILength is the number of bytes that the packet contains. plData is the  packet for which data needs to be checked. As it is, the function works. But it works bit for bit. It needs to be improved to work byte for byte. So to all genius c++ developers out there who far surpasses my knowledge. Any ideas will be really helpful. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I don't follow. Why does it need to be improved?

Comment: As it is it is obviously a good function. Bitwise as it is, is quite effective. But as a newbie developer. If the boss wants the toilet on the roof then thats where it will be... If you do have any questions. simply ask and I will try answer as best I can

Comment: In what sense would making it work byte for byte be an improvement? (You can find a byte for byte CRC32 function [here](http://www.csbruce.com/software/crc32.c).)

Comment: Point taken. Making it work byte for byte would in fact not be an improvement since  for a given input remainder and generator polynomial, the output remainder will always be the same. Thus in theory it should be of the same effectiveness.

Comment: Thanks for responding with the byte for byte function. I really appreciate it. Speaking from experience. A lot of programmer bosses can be idiots. I was once asked to implement a timer that would fire once a day for a windows service. and the boss did not want the service to be run by task schedular

Comment: I'm going to give you one of the most valuable pieces of information I have ever acquired in my life. You'll probably think I'm crazy, but this is truly valuable. When asked to do something stupid, don't do it. It doesn't benefit anyone, even the person who asked you to do it. Eventually, you will find people who will value your ability to keep them from causing stupid things to happen. Once you have a reputation for doing stupid things, even if it's because you were asked to do them, you will never have the value a person who doesn't do stupid things has.

Comment: I have to agree with you on that. If I take myself for example. I am straight out of university. Now every job you begin with, you work on a probation period. This makes it very difficult for you. You wan't to keep your job, you are still learning and its tough. I am on my last day of probation and I had a screw that moment recently. I implemented something way more practical than what was asked. I am very lucky to have an older brother who taught me a lot of good principles in programming. I would have been so lost without that guidance.

Comment: The boss is often, but not always an idiot.  In this case the request is very reasonable since a bit-wise CRC is very slow compared to a table-driven byte-wise CRC.  All reasonable CRC implementations process eight bits or more at a time.

Comment: @MarkAdler: That's the risk with my strategy. If you're the idiot, it fails horribly. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Ross Williams excellent tutorial on CRCs](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt), especially section 9 on "A Table-Driven Implementation", which calculates the CRC a byte at a time instead of a bit at a time.  You can also look at the somewhat more involved [CRC implementation in zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c), which calculates it four bytes at a time.  You can also calculate it [eight bytes at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645167/implementing-sse-4-2s-crc32c-in-software).

Comment: Very nice tutorial indeed. Thanks. :)