# Is there a LINUX command line tool for CRC32C (Castagnoli)

Tags: linux, google-cloud-storage, crc, crc32

I need to verify data using CRC32C, the Castagnoli variant of CRC32 calculation. I cannot find a self-contained command line utility anywhere that will calculate this to verify the values in question. CRC32? MD5? SHA? Check. CRC32C? You lose.

I need a program. Has to be self contained (no non-standard PERL or Python modules that require installation...standard ones are okay). Probably no Java, as I cannot guarantee a Java installation. Ruby is right out.

Clever "gzip" or "tar" tricks are fine. Needs to run on OS-X, Linux, and maybe Android.

I could indeed write one (the code is in the RFC), but c'mon...that's sort of like

*"hmmm, my car uses synthetic oil...time for an oil change, let me go to the local refinery and make a few quarts"*

or

*"Uncle Bill wants a PB&J sandwich, but has a gluten allergy...let me go get some rice flour and make gluten-free bread"*.

I found some libraries to calculate CRC32Cs, but no programs. Grumble.

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects?hl=ja

Comment: Trivia: SSE4.2 has an instruction for this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#SSE4.2 (mind blown)

Comment: I know, saw that...pretty amazin, eh?

Comment: A online CRC32C calculator is available at https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

Answer (score 13):

Starting with 4.4, gsutil supports a 'hash' command that can compute hashes like so:

```
gsutil hash filename
```

It will output CRC32C and MD5 by default.

Comment: Installing the native crcmod is a bit ugly because it requires to uninstall the existing one. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CRC32CandInstallingcrcmod#debian-and-ubuntu

Comment: First `pip install gsutil`.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you can compile C code, you can find the program you're looking for in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646775/1180620).  It will also use the Intel `crc32` instruction if available.

Comment: Is there an easy to use command line tool that calculate crc32c of large files by reading chunks?

Comment: If you compile the program at that link with `TEST` defined, then you have your command-line tool.

Comment: It's working with "gcc -D TEST crc32c.c -o crc32c -lpthread" and "cat bigfile | ./crc32c" Thanks.

Comment: Or simply `./crc32c < bigfile`.

Comment: (5 years later...)  As of Dec 2023 the linked page Mark Adler gave (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646775/1180620) does not contain the code -DTEST apparently used to enable, i.e. -DTEST does not include a main program to make a complete executable.

Does anyone know where those bits (to make a command line tool) are now?

Comment: @jimav I put the TEST code back.

Answer (score 1):

gsutil will include a new "hash" command in the next release (gsutil 4.4) - which should be out pretty soon.