# Why SSE4.2 CRC32 hash value is different with software CRC32 hash value?

Tags: hash, crc32

In my project, CRC32 is calculated very many times.
I have used software CRC32 calculation until now.
But I noticed there is CPU support in SSE4.2 and linux also provides the hardware CRC32 calculation function using the CPU instruction.
I use Intel Xeon E5-2650 CPU so I tried to calculate CRC32 by using the linux function.
But the result is different with software CRC32 function that I used.
I used init value 127 in the both. Software CRC32 function I used is below

```
static uint32_t crc32_tab[] = {
0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba, 0x076dc419, 0x706af48f,
0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3, 0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4, 0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988,
0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07, 0x90bf1d91, 0x1db71064, 0x6ab020f2,
0xf3b97148, 0x84be41de, 0x1adad47d, 0x6ddde4eb, 0xf4d4b551, 0x83d385c7,
0x136c9856, 0x646ba8c0, 0xfd62f97a, 0x8a65c9ec, 0x14015c4f, 0x63066cd9,
0xfa0f3d63, 0x8d080df5, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x4c69105e, 0xd56041e4, 0xa2677172,
0x3c03e4d1, 0x4b04d447, 0xd20d85fd, 0xa50ab56b, 0x35b5a8fa, 0x42b2986c,
0xdbbbc9d6, 0xacbcf940, 0x32d86ce3, 0x45df5c75, 0xdcd60dcf, 0xabd13d59,
0x26d930ac, 0x51de003a, 0xc8d75180, 0xbfd06116, 0x21b4f4b5, 0x56b3c423,
0xcfba9599, 0xb8bda50f, 0x2802b89e, 0x5f058808, 0xc60cd9b2, 0xb10be924,
0x2f6f7c87, 0x58684c11, 0xc1611dab, 0xb6662d3d, 0x76dc4190, 0x01db7106,
0x98d220bc, 0xefd5102a, 0x71b18589, 0x06b6b51f, 0x9fbfe4a5, 0xe8b8d433,
0x7807c9a2, 0x0f00f934, 0x9609a88e, 0xe10e9818, 0x7f6a0dbb, 0x086d3d2d,
0x91646c97, 0xe6635c01, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x1c6c6162, 0x856530d8, 0xf262004e,
0x6c0695ed, 0x1b01a57b, 0x8208f4c1, 0xf50fc457, 0x65b0d9c6, 0x12b7e950,
0x8bbeb8ea, 0xfcb9887c, 0x62dd1ddf, 0x15da2d49, 0x8cd37cf3, 0xfbd44c65,
0x4db26158, 0x3ab551ce, 0xa3bc0074, 0xd4bb30e2, 0x4adfa541, 0x3dd895d7,
0xa4d1c46d, 0xd3d6f4fb, 0x4369e96a, 0x346ed9fc, 0xad678846, 0xda60b8d0,
0x44042d73, 0x33031de5, 0xaa0a4c5f, 0xdd0d7cc9, 0x5005713c, 0x270241aa,
0xbe0b1010, 0xc90c2086, 0x5768b525, 0x206f85b3, 0xb966d409, 0xce61e49f,
0x5edef90e, 0x29d9c998, 0xb0d09822, 0xc7d7a8b4, 0x59b33d17, 0x2eb40d81,
0xb7bd5c3b, 0xc0ba6cad, 0xedb88320, 0x9abfb3b6, 0x03b6e20c, 0x74b1d29a,
0xead54739, 0x9dd277af, 0x04db2615, 0x73dc1683, 0xe3630b12, 0x94643b84,
0x0d6d6a3e, 0x7a6a5aa8, 0xe40ecf0b, 0x9309ff9d, 0x0a00ae27, 0x7d079eb1,
0xf00f9344, 0x8708a3d2, 0x1e01f268, 0x6906c2fe, 0xf762575d, 0x806567cb,
0x196c3671, 0x6e6b06e7, 0xfed41b76, 0x89d32be0, 0x10da7a5a, 0x67dd4acc,
0xf9b9df6f, 0x8ebeeff9, 0x17b7be43, 0x60b08ed5, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xa1d1937e,
0x38d8c2c4, 0x4fdff252, 0xd1bb67f1, 0xa6bc5767, 0x3fb506dd, 0x48b2364b,
0xd80d2bda, 0xaf0a1b4c, 0x36034af6, 0x41047a60, 0xdf60efc3, 0xa867df55,
0x316e8eef, 0x4669be79, 0xcb61b38c, 0xbc66831a, 0x256fd2a0, 0x5268e236,
0xcc0c7795, 0xbb0b4703, 0x220216b9, 0x5505262f, 0xc5ba3bbe, 0xb2bd0b28,
0x2bb45a92, 0x5cb36a04, 0xc2d7ffa7, 0xb5d0cf31, 0x2cd99e8b, 0x5bdeae1d,
0x9b64c2b0, 0xec63f226, 0x756aa39c, 0x026d930a, 0x9c0906a9, 0xeb0e363f,
0x72076785, 0x05005713, 0x95bf4a82, 0xe2b87a14, 0x7bb12bae, 0x0cb61b38,
0x92d28e9b, 0xe5d5be0d, 0x7cdcefb7, 0x0bdbdf21, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xf1d4e242,
0x68ddb3f8, 0x1fda836e, 0x81be16cd, 0xf6b9265b, 0x6fb077e1, 0x18b74777,
0x88085ae6, 0xff0f6a70, 0x66063bca, 0x11010b5c, 0x8f659eff, 0xf862ae69,
0x616bffd3, 0x166ccf45, 0xa00ae278, 0xd70dd2ee, 0x4e048354, 0x3903b3c2,
0xa7672661, 0xd06016f7, 0x4969474d, 0x3e6e77db, 0xaed16a4a, 0xd9d65adc,
0x40df0b66, 0x37d83bf0, 0xa9bcae53, 0xdebb9ec5, 0x47b2cf7f, 0x30b5ffe9,
0xbdbdf21c, 0xcabac28a, 0x53b39330, 0x24b4a3a6, 0xbad03605, 0xcdd70693,
0x54de5729, 0x23d967bf, 0xb3667a2e, 0xc4614ab8, 0x5d681b02, 0x2a6f2b94,
0xb40bbe37, 0xc30c8ea1, 0x5a05df1b, 0x2d02ef8d
};

uint32_t crc32(uint32_t crc, const void *buf, size_t size)
{
    const uint8_t *p;

    p = buf;
    crc = 127;

    while (size--)
        crc = crc32_tab[(crc ^ *p++) & 0xFF] ^ (crc >> 8);

    return crc ^ ~0U;
}
```

Comment: There are different CRC32s - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: There is no easy way to answer this.  Find a known good reference data set and CRC32 value.  Use this known good reference to compare with your various usages and verify you get the correct CRC32 value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That table is for the "standard" CRC-32 used in ethernet, zip, gzip, v.42, many other places.

I need to point out that that code in your question is incorrect, with the `crc = 127;` statement.  `crc` should not be set at all, since it is an input to the function that is then lost, and it should not be initialized to `127`.  What should be there is `crc = ~crc;`.  That should also be the approach used at the end, instead of `return crc ^ ~0U;`.  That may not be portable if `unsigned` is not the same size at `uint32_t`.  The use of `~` is fine with `uint32_t`, but if a different type is used that is not 32 bits, then more portable still is `crc ^ 0xffffffff`.

Anyway, to answer your question, Intel chose a different 32-bit CRC to implement in their hardware instruction.  That CRC is usually referred to as CRC-32C, using a polynomial discovered by Castagnoli (what the "C" refers to) with better properties than the polynomial used in the standard CRC-32.  iSCSI and SCTP use the CRC-32C instead of CRC-32.  I presume that that had something to do with Intel's choice.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646775/1180620) for code that computes the CRC-32C in software, as well as in hardware if available.

Comment: I don`t know that the hardware instruction uses CRC32C. Thx :)

Comment: I have a question about standard CRC32 that I used. Is the crc not a seed value? then what is seed?

Comment: You need to make the changes I gave in my answer to the code in your question.  Then you can use `crc32()` to compute the CRC-32 of a sequence of bytes either all at once, or piecemeal.  The starting value to pass to the `crc` parameter of the function is then `0`.  If you are doing it piecemeal, then for the next call you pass the CRC value returned from the last call.