# 256 bit CRC calculation on AVX2

Tags: x86, intel, simd, crc, avx2

64 bit CRC function exists on Intel SSE4.2 intrinsics.

```
unsigned __int64 _mm_crc32_u64 (unsigned __int64 crc, unsigned __int64 v)
```

However I can't find 256 bit version of CRC calculation on AVX2 intrinsics. 
I'm using  256 bit variables (**__m256i**) on my program, so I want to calculate crc (or hash) over 256 bits. How can I do this operation with Intel AVX2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`_mm_crc32_u64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_crc32_u64&expand=1228) is not a SIMD intrinsic, even though it's notionally part of SSE4.2 - it is just a normal scalar instruction which operates on 64 bit values. So it makes no sense to talk about 128 bit or 256 bit SIMD versions - you just need to apply it in a loop to an array of unsigned 64 bit values.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15754706/253056) for a fuller explanation of the various x86 CRC32 instructions and intrinsics.

Comment: In that case, should I sum the crc values that coming from each 4 loops ?
Because I want to represent 256 bit as a one crc value.

Comment: You should not be adding CRCs - you should just cumulatively CRC all the data you are generating, in the correct sequence. If this is still not clear then you might need to start a new question, explain what you're trying to do, and include the relevant part of your existing code.

Comment: On the other hand, Is it logical to apply sub operations (shifting, XOR, MOD2 etc.) to 256 bit vector like _mm_crc32_u64  function ?

Comment: No, CRC is a sequential operation, so unless you want to generate separate CRCs for separate streams of data in parallel then you would just generate one CRC with a scalar loop, as already described in the answer above.

Comment: I understand _mm_crc32_u64 operation now but I want to calculate CRC using 256bit (at least 128 bit) in one sequence for improving performance. I will ask a new question.